# Calculator Starting on a number

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make it so when the app opens it will begin on a number and subtract/add 1 to that number like 20. So when they click +1 it will go to 21 instead of beginning from 0. Thx for the help.

```
    int counter;
Button add , sub; 
TextView D1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    D1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Adds 1 to the counter
            counter = counter + 1;
            D1.setText(" " + counter);

        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Subtract 1 from counter
            counter = counter - 1;
            D1.setText(" " + counter);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: initialise `counter = 20;` ????

Answer (score 4):

Just initialize the counter with a value of your choice. 
So for example, if you want it to be 20, do

```
counter = 20;
```

Or if you want it to be a random number, you can use the Random class.

```
Random generator = new Random();
counter = generator.nextInt(); //If you want it to be any random integer value
counter = generator.nextInt(50); //If you want any random integer value from (inclusively 0,  exclusively 50)
```

So it could look something like this:

```
int counter;
Button add, sub; 
Random generator;
TextView D1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    generator = new Random();
    counter = generator.nextInt(50);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    D1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    D1.setText(" " + counter);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Adds 1 to the counter
            counter = counter + 1;
            D1.setText(" " + counter);

        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Subtract 1 from counter
            counter = counter - 1;
            D1.setText(" " + counter);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: As I can't give you +10 through a comment, I'll do it here. Good answer, anyway.